# Decoding text in python

Tags: python

I want to know how to decode certain text, and have found some text like this which I want to decode:

```
\xe2\x80\x93
```

I know that printing it will solve it, but I am building a web crawler hence I need to build an index (dictionary) containing words with a list of URLs where the word appears.

Hence I want to do something like this:

```
dic = {}
dic['\xe2\x80\x93'] = 'http://example.com' #this is the url where the word appears
```

... but when I do:

```
print dic
```

I get:

```
'\xe2\x80\x93'
```

... instead of `â€“`.

But when I do `print dic['\xe2\x80\x93']` I successfully get `â€“`.

Howe can I get `â€“` by `print dic` also?

Answer (score 0):

When you see `\xhh`, that is a a character escape sequence. In this case, it is showing you the hex value of the character (see: [lexical analysis: string-literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)).

The reason you see `\xhh` sometimes, and you see the actual characters when you use `print` is related to the [difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).